# Kotlin to Java, decompiled Java file very large,why?

Tags: kotlin

Why is the decompiled Java file very large when using IDEA’s Kotlin to Java decompiler plug-in to decompile a Kotlin file into a Java file? Why? Does anyone know? Thank you[![enter image description here]

**This is the source code of the Kotlin file, very simple**
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/soBIL.png]

**This is a decompiled java file, super large, more than 10,000 lines of code**
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M44mg.png]

Comment: I haven't confirmed this, but the obvious explanation would be that GlobalScope.launch() is an `inline` function.

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been solved, just upgrade IDEA to the latest version.